# Implement a recursive program that displays all combinations of operators to reach a given sum

Tags: c#, recursion

- I have to write a program that displays all the combinations of operators( + and -), to put between numbers from 1 to N (N>=2), in order to reach a targeted value X. It should write "N/A" if there is no possibility.

> For the input:

- n=6
- x=3

> It displays:

- 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3
- 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3
- 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
       static bool counter;

       static void Generate(int n, int x, int currentIndex, int result, string expression)
        {
            counter = true;

            if (currentIndex == n + 1)
            {
                if (result == x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(expression + " = " + x);
                }

                return;
            }

            Generate(n, x, currentIndex + 1, result + currentIndex, expression + " + " + currentIndex);
            Generate(n, x, currentIndex + 1, result - currentIndex, expression + " - " + currentIndex);
        }

       static void Main()
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            const int doi = 2;

            Generate(n, x, doi, 1, "1");

            if (!counter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("N/A");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
>  It gives me the error : JRM003 (Error) : Don't use static fields. (line: 7, character: 7).
> ```
>
> Where can I place the "counter" in order to track if there is possibility of reaching to the targeted value, and get rid of the error.

Comment: "Don't use static fields" isn't an _error_, it seems almost like a code style rule applied by your IDE or some other custom configuration. Is it preventing your code from compiling? Are you asking how you can refactor your code to not use a static field?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, you are right.

Comment: So what's the question? Why are you getting the message in the first place? How to remove the use of the static field?

Comment: My question is how to refactor the code to not use static field but keeping it's functionality.

Comment: Simply delete counter and every reference to it. A static field that is always true is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. Count in binary treating 0 as subtraction and 1 as addition:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n, x;
        String response1, response2;

        Console.Write("Enter a value for 'n' [n>=2]: ");
        response1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter a value for 'x': ");
        response2 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(response1, out n) && int.TryParse(response2, out x))
        {
            if (n >= 2)
            {
                List<String> solutions = new List<string>();
                int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray();
                int width = numbers.Length - 1;
                int max = (int)Math.Pow(2, numbers.Length - 1);
                for(int i=0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    int sum = numbers[0];
                    String binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(width, '0');
                    String equation = numbers[0].ToString();
                    for(int d=0; d<binary.Length; d++)
                    {
                        char operation = binary[d];
                        equation = equation + ((operation == '0') ? " - " : " + ") + numbers[d + 1];
                        sum = sum + ((operation == '0') ? -1 : 1) * numbers[d + 1];
                    }
                    equation = equation + " = " + sum;
                    if (sum == x)
                    {
                        solutions.Add(equation);
                    }
                }
                if (solutions.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("N/A");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(String solution in solutions)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(solution);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'n' must be greater than or equal to 2.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid value for 'n' or 'x'!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter a value for 'n' [n>=2]: 6
Enter a value for 'x': 3
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3
1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3
Press Enter to Quit.
```

Comment: ...except I didn't use RECURSION. Don't remember seeing that in your title before...